# Access nested JSON in json2html

Tags: javascript, html, json2html

I'm using json2html to create a report for a given JSON file. I was wondering what exactly the syntax is to access nested objects and their fields. For example,

```
var jsonData = {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",

    "nestedObject": {
        "nestedField1": "nestedValue1",
        "nestedField2": "nestedValue2"
    }
}
```

What's the syntax to access `"nestedField1"`? The transform that I'm using is,

```
var transform = [ 
                  {tag : "h1", html : "${field1}"},
                  {tag : "article", html : "${field2}"},
                  {tag : "article", html : "${nestedObject}" }
                ]
```

The last statement `html : "${nestedObject}"` returns `[Object object]` as expected. But, I can't seem to access its fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"${nestedObject.nestedField1}"
```

This should do the trick.

Just like how you'd access it in JS:

```
jsonData.nestedObject.nestedField1
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized this relatively simple thing just a moment before you posted.

Answer (score 0):

I should have tried everything that seemed intuitive.

The simple way is,

```
{ tag : "article", html : "the first nested field is ${nestedObject.nestedField1}" }
```

Comment: Just like I answered ;-)